# Как отобразить модель базы данных в postgresql?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, моделирование

Как сделать скриншоты таблиц в postgresql?

---

Сделала базу данных в postgesql. Теперь надо эти таблички "увидеть" не в виде кода типа "create table ", а в виде нормальных табличек, соединенных между собой, и заскриншотить их для последующего отчета по бд.

Comment: select * from your_table в консоли постгреса или в Вашем любимом GUI для БД, а потом Alt+PrintScreen -> word -> Ctrl+V.

Comment: Мне интересно, а есть свежие реализации на данный вопрос? Не добавили никаких вариантов, чтобы в самом pgadmin можно было делать это?

Answer (score 4):

Данную возможность поддерживает большинство средств из данного списка https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/GUI_Database_Design_Tools

Рекомендую средства, которые отображают не просто связь между таблицами, а между атрибутами:

1. [DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/features/tour/references-graphs/)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. [Valentina Studio](http://www.valentina-db.com/ru/valentina-database-modeling)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. [pgModeller](https://pgmodeler.com.br/), но формат не очень красивый [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

> Сделала базу данных в postgesql. Теперь надо эти таблички "увидеть" не в виде кода типа "create table ", а в виде нормальных табличек, соединенных между собой, и заскриншотить их для последующего отчета по бд.

Для этих целей, есть средства моделирования в нотации UML, например [`Lucidchart (Flow Chart Maker & Online Diagram Software)`](https://www.lucidchart.com/). Вы можете "посмотреть" на таблицы из консоли выполнив команду `\d`

[image]

Если нужны именно данные в таблицах, то делайте запрос в таблицу

```
     SELECT * FROM my_table;
```