# Программа для моделирования базы данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, моделирование

Подскажите, какие в природе существуют программы для моделирования БД.

В приоритете, конечно же бесплатные версии.

Пользовался Toad Data Modeler, но триал кончился...

Comment: Какая хоть база? Для `MS SQL` майкрософтский `Management Studio` например...

Comment: @AGS17, да, но на сколько я помню, там 1 вид связи и нету, например, пунктирных линий. Т.е она беднее, чем Toad Data Modeler.

Comment: ERwin Data Modeler 

Comment: Sybase PowerDesigner. Правда он то же платный, но на рутрекере есть, если что

Comment: что еще за один вид связей, и пунктирные линии? Вы хотите физическую модель строить или реляционную?

Comment: @teran Физическая модель от логической отличается наличием типов данных и именованием таблиц.

Comment: @Alex78191 я предположил, что разные типы линий для автор хочет видеть для разных типов связей _многие-ко-многим_, например, чтобы соединять два объекта не используя промежуточную  сущность. Очевидно, что на уровне физической модели, которая строится в SSMS такого быть не может. Поэтому говорить что инструмент _беднее_ некорректно, ибо уровень проектирования другой. инфологическую надо было видимо сказать, а не реляционную/логическую.

Comment: @Alex78191, кончай уже сомнительные правки делать?

Comment: @Qwertiy это правка, улучшающая поиск вопроса.

Comment: Моделирование значит создание по готовой базе диаграммы?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/315124/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-postgresql/676187#676187

Answer (score 1):

Все программы вам вряд ли перечислят, но можно воспользоваться Википедией - там обычно есть полезные статьи по сравнению различных типов ПО, в т.ч. и по тому, что вам нужно.

Вот нужная статья:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_modeling_tools

Comment: Еще есть категория https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Data_modeling_tools

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/?fromMenu). По-моему, одно из лучших средств. Единственное - DataGrip **платный**. Но есть триал + можно взять студенческую/opensource лицензию. Если не студент, то в месяц 8.90$ стоит, что совсем немного :)

Comment: Он же, вроде, для администратирования? Или в нем все таки можно проектировать БД?

Comment: @iluxa1810 проектируйте SQL-ем, а не тасканием мышкой. А красивую раскладку диаграммы DataGrip вам сделает.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Это называется не проектирование, а создание. Еще скажите, что IDEF1 не нужна.