# Как в БД Zabbix events связан с hosts?

Tags: zabbix

Здравствуйте.

Возникло желание создать свой кастомный отчет по событиям zabbix в детализации по хостам.
Нашел таблицу c информацией о событиях,

```
SELECT eventid, source, `object`, objectid, clock, value, acknowledged, ns
FROM zabbix.events
```

нашел zabbix.hosts и zabbix.host_inventory.

каким образом zabbix.events связана с zabbix.hosts?

Подозреваю, что возможно через objectid, но как...

Comment: Почему API не используешь?

Comment: планирую использовать эту информацию в большом аналитическом отчете по двум системам мониторинга, предполагаю, что через Zabbix API будет медленнее, да и вдруг если возникнет необходимость вернуть данные, которые придется выкручивать 2 обращениями к API. Понимаю, что переход на новую версию может поломать этот велосипед.

Comment: Можно через [DbVisualizer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/315124/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-postgresql/676187#676187) или MySQL Workbench посмотреть связи между таблицами с помощью графической схемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в результате компиляции информации получился вот такой select, в нем вы можете проследить все связи

```
SELECT * FROM events
JOIN triggers ON events.objectid = triggers.triggerid
JOIN functions ON functions.triggerid = triggers.triggerid
JOIN items ON items.itemid = functions.itemid
JOIN hosts ON items.hostid = hosts.hostid
WHERE events.source = 0 
AND 
LOWER(hosts.host) like 'mysql%' 
AND events.clock>=unix_timestamp('2017-09-25 09:55:00') 
AND events.clock<=unix_timestamp('2017-09-25 11:00:00') 
ORDER BY events.clock DESC
;
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Я долго искал, как же связаны таблицы items и triggers.
Оказалось, что через таблицу functions.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой при написании скрипта через API
Единственное, что при таком подходе (через API) вместо functions я сразу иду к item-ам по по полученному triggerid:

```
item.get(triggerids=[<triggerid>])
```